# wkhtmltopdf generates a blank pdf file on AWS Lambda in nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, wkhtmltopdf

wkhtmltopdf generates a blank pdf file on AWS Lambda in nodejs.

I want to distill PDF file from html on AWS Lambda using wkhtmltopdf for convert to pdf.

Lambda zip package contains [wkhtmltopdf Linux 64 bit biinary](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz).

I write this code (TypeScript).

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';
const wkhtmltopdf = 'wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf';


export function htmlToPdf(html:string, outputPath:string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const onelineHtml = html.replace(/\r?\n/g,"");
        exec(`echo '${onelineHtml}' | ${wkhtmltopdf} --encoding utf-8 - ${outputPath}`, (err, stdout) => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(stdout);
        });    
    });
}
```

input HTML is here.

```
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Settlement</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test</h1>
sumPrice: 100yen
</body>
</html>
```

Above codes can generate a PDF file, but the file is blank I opened it by PDF Viewer like OSX's preview app and Adobe PDF Reader.
And the PDF file has objects following the image, opened by text editor (likes emacs).

[Image: Generated PDF file's contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXbNT.png)

I'd like to know what I should do to settle this problem.
I want to distill PDF from HTML on AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I think it generated a zero size pdf file,
Lambda support 64 bit binary files. you need to upload a suitable version of wkhtmltopdf.sh file.

Answer (score 0):

Generating and sending PDF file in lambda can be achieved as following:

1. Write a lambda function that generates a pdf file from html content.
2. In this function, do not use "buffer" as a the type. Instead use "file" - it could be created in folder /tmp/sample.pdf
3. Update response.body with command fs.readFileSync('/tmp/temp.pdf').toString("base64"), which is returned to calling function.
4. Calling function can straight away use this payload in SES Raw file (no need to further encode as base64.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i did following code in lambda please increase Memory And Timeout which are located at Basic Setting in Lambda Function.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const pdf = require('html-pdf');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: "AK****S****D****Q",
    secretAccessKey: "vBK******Q****KyT***W*****h**l"
});
function genpdf(params){
    let res = {
        status : false
    };
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        pdf.create(params.html,params.pdfSetting).toStream(async function (err, stream) {
            if (err) {
                return resolve(res);
            }
            let currentTime = new Date()
            let path = "pdfs/"+currentTime.getFullYear()+"/"+(currentTime.getMonth() + 1)+"/"+currentTime.getDate()+"/";
            const s3params = {
                Bucket: 'checkdc', // pass your bucket name
                Key: path+params.fileName, // file will be saved as Year/Month/Date/abc.pdf
                Body: stream, 
                ContentType: 'application/pdf',
                ACL : 'public-read' // Remove this key if you want to upload file private
            };
            s3.upload(s3params, function(s3Err, data) {
                if (s3Err) {
                    return resolve(res);
                }
                console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`);
                res.status = true;
                res.body = data.Location;
                return resolve(res);
            });
        });

    })
}

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => { 
    console.log("event.body :: ",event.body)
    var params = JSON.parse(event.body);
    let data = await genpdf(params);
    let response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
    return response;
};
```